# LightSwitch 2013 HTML Client can't break in Javascript

Tags: lightswitch-2013

WinServer 2008 R2 OS. Visual Studio Premium 2013 with 'LightSwitch for Visual Studio.'

I came back to a working VS2013 LightSwitch HTML client project that had been debugging OK in its previous implementation.

Went to do some alterations and now I can't get the lsml.js files to debug.
i.e.

1) When debugging the breakPoints in the JS show as 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols loaded...'

2) debugger statements inserted into the script(s) are ignored.

The .cs controller code breaks OK when the JScript calls the API for Data.

I have checked all  Solution projects are debug build.

Made a test Solution / project and it is the same ( no JS debug)

Just tested VS2012 and it is the same so I so it seems there is a setting somewhere that I have mucked up but I can't figure it out. Environment variable maybe?

I only do Lightswitch work infrequently so it could have been broken for weeks. 
Any thoughts on what to check would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only after a complete re-install of Vs2013 did the penny drop. You need IE set as your default browser if you want the IDE break points to be hit. I must have moved to Firefox after the last time I worked on the project.